# How to drag from wpf treeview and drop on winform control?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using EasyGis.net shape file and my application is a wpf . I am using a treeview in wpf and shapefile which is a winform control.

I want to know that how can i do drag an item from treeview and drop on the winform shapefile control?

Comment: I doubt this is possible without some very hardcore drag and drop coding utilizing the clipboard, OLE automation and possibly some magic pixie dust.  You are, after all, asking for a way to drag an object from one UI system and drop it into a completely different (and largely incompatlble) UI system.

Comment: final requirement ?

Comment: final requirement is to drop some markers from treeview in shape file and display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an invisible border around the winform control to get the drop functionality and then if the winform control has methods to add and show the markers use those methods